# Is a constexpr size needed for initialising an array with an explicit size?

Tags: c++, c++11

*C++ Primer (5th edition)*  states that when an array is initialised with a size, the size provided has to be a `constexpr`, like this:

```
int arr[10];

// or

constexpr size_t sz = 10;
int arr[sz];
```

However, this code compiles just fine for me:

```
size_t sz = 10;
int arr[sz];
```

So, is the `constexpr` really needed?

Comment: `size_t sz = 10;
int arr[sz];` is illegal.  If you are using gcc, compile using `-pedantic-errors` to stop it from compiling.  You **always** need a compile time constant for array sizes in C++.

Comment: Note that `const size_t sz = 10;` is also valid, since `constexpr` is relatively new to the C++ language.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling (`g++ -pedantic --std=c++11 -o t t.cpp`) in pedantic mode gives:

```
t.cpp:5:8: warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]
int arr[sz];
       ^
1 warning generated.
```

You may even reject the code with `-pedantic-errors`.

> [C++11: 8.3.4/1]: In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> D1 [ constant-expressionopt ] attribute-specifier-seqopt [..]

Thus any constant is acceptable, constexpr or const variables.